# convex region with 7 vertices

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let, $X$ be a convex region in the plane bounded by straight lines.

Let, $X$ have $7$ vertices. Suppose $f(x,y)=ax+by+c$ has maximum value $M$ & minimum value $N$ on $X$ & $N<M$. Let, $S=\{P:P$ is a vertex of $X$ & $N<f(P)<M\}.$

If $S$ has $n$ elements then, which is **TRUE** ?

(a) $n$ can't be $5$.

(b) $n$ can't be $3$.

(c) $n$ can be $2$.

(d) $n$ can be $4$.

I drew the figure & tried into contradictory way, but I could not solve it.

Please help.....

Comment: Just picture tilting a seven-sided polygon.  How many vertices can be the lowest or the highest?  If you tilt it toward a point, then $1$ vertex is the unique lowest; if you tilt it toward an edge, then $2$ are tied for lowest.  Similarly, either $1$ or $2$ can be the highest.  So the number of vertices that are lowest or highest can be either $2$, $3$, or $4$, leaving $5$, $4$, or $3$ that are neither lowest nor highest.

Answer (score 3):

The key point is: A polygon can rest either on a single vertex or on its edge ( having two vertices at its ends). You can think of a similar situation for its top also thereby leaving 5, 4 or 3 vertices in the middle section. Option d must be true.